# create a stopwatch in wpf when the window first appear

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

i'm building a slide puzzle in wpf (VB.NET- Visual Studio 2012) and i alredy wrote the code for it but i need to had a stopwatch that will appear at the window loading first time. i also need that the stopwatch will be elapsed and start again when the user shuffles the puzzle. please give me some tips to write the right code. thx.
that's the code for the slide puzzle:

Public Class level2
    Dim win(15) As BitmapImage
    Dim wrong(15) As BitmapImage
    Dim mess(15) As BitmapImage
    Dim images(15) As Image
    Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded

```
    Dim h1 As New BitmapImage
    h1.BeginInit()
    h1.UriSource = New Uri("images2/h1.gif", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    h1.EndInit()

    Dim h2 As New BitmapImage
    h2.BeginInit()
    h2.UriSource = New Uri("images2/h2.gif", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    h2.EndInit()

    Dim h3 As New BitmapImage
    h3.BeginInit()
    h3.UriSource = New Uri("images2/h3.gif", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    h3.EndInit()

    Dim h4 As New BitmapImage
    h4.BeginInit()
    h4.UriSource = New Uri("images2/h4.gif", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    h4.EndInit()

    Dim h5 As New BitmapImage
    h5.BeginInit()
    h5.UriSource = New Uri("images2/h5.gif", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    h5.EndInit()

    Dim h6 As New BitmapImage
    h6.BeginInit()
    h6.UriSource = New Uri("images2/h6.gif", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    h6.EndInit()

    Dim h7 As New BitmapImage
    h7.BeginInit()
    h7.UriSource = New Uri("images2/h7.gif", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    h7.EndInit()

    Dim h8 As New BitmapImage
    h8.BeginInit()
    h8.UriSource = New Uri("images2/h8.gif", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    h8.EndInit()

    Dim h9 As New BitmapImage
    h9.BeginInit()
    h9.UriSource = New Uri("images2/h9.gif", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    h9.EndInit()

    Dim h10 As New BitmapImage
    h10.BeginInit()
    h10.UriSource = New Uri("images2/h10.gif", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    h10.EndInit()

    Dim h11 As New BitmapImage
    h11.BeginInit()
    h11.UriSource = New Uri("images2/h11.gif", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    h11.EndInit()

    Dim h12 As New BitmapImage
    h12.BeginInit()
    h12.UriSource = New Uri("images2/h12.gif", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    h12.EndInit()

    Dim h13 As New BitmapImage
    h13.BeginInit()
    h13.UriSource = New Uri("images2/h13.gif", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    h13.EndInit()

    Dim h14 As New BitmapImage
    h14.BeginInit()
    h14.UriSource = New Uri("images2/h14.gif", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    h14.EndInit()

    Dim h15 As New BitmapImage
    h15.BeginInit()
    h15.UriSource = New Uri("images2/h15.gif", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    h15.EndInit()

    win(0) = h1
    win(1) = h2
    win(2) = h3
    win(3) = h4
    win(4) = h5
    win(5) = h6
    win(6) = h7
    win(7) = h8
    win(8) = h9
    win(9) = h10
    win(10) = h11
    win(11) = h12
    win(12) = h13
    win(13) = h14
    win(14) = h15
    win(15) = Nothing

    wrong(0) = h4
    wrong(1) = h1
    wrong(2) = h7
    wrong(3) = h14
    wrong(4) = h5
    wrong(5) = h13
    wrong(6) = h8
    wrong(7) = h10
    wrong(8) = h6
    wrong(9) = h2
    wrong(10) = h12
    wrong(11) = h15
    wrong(12) = h3
    wrong(13) = h11
    wrong(14) = h9
    wrong(15) = Nothing



    images(0) = flower0
    images(1) = flower1
    images(2) = flower2
    images(3) = flower3
    images(4) = flower4
    images(5) = flower5
    images(6) = flower6
    images(7) = flower7
    images(8) = flower8
    images(9) = flower9
    images(10) = flower10
    images(11) = flower11
    images(12) = flower12
    images(13) = flower13
    images(14) = flower14
    images(15) = flower15

    For i As Integer = 0 To wrong.Length - 1
        images(i).Source = wrong(i)
    Next

End Sub

Sub checkwin()
    Dim flag As Boolean = False

    For i As Integer = 0 To win.Length - 1
        If mess(i) Is win(i) Then
            flag = True
        Else
            flag = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If flag = True Then
        lbl2.Content = "You Win!!"
    End If

End Sub

Sub checkcells(ByRef pic1 As Image, ByRef pic2 As Image)

    If pic2.Source Is Nothing Then
        pic2.Source = pic1.Source
        pic1.Source = Nothing
    End If


End Sub


Sub update()

    For i As Integer = 0 To mess.Length - 1
        mess(i) = images(i).Source

    Next
End Sub


Private Sub flower0_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles flower0.MouseDown
    checkcells(flower0, flower1)
    checkcells(flower0, flower4)
    update()
    checkwin()
End Sub

Private Sub flower1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles flower1.MouseDown
    checkcells(flower1, flower0)
    checkcells(flower1, flower2)
    checkcells(flower1, flower5)
    update()
    checkwin()
End Sub

Private Sub flower2_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles flower2.MouseDown
    checkcells(flower2, flower1)
    checkcells(flower2, flower3)
    checkcells(flower2, flower6)
    update()
    checkwin()
End Sub

Private Sub flower3_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles flower3.MouseDown
    checkcells(flower3, flower2)
    checkcells(flower3, flower7)

    update()
    checkwin()
End Sub

Private Sub flower4_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles flower4.MouseDown
    checkcells(flower4, flower0)
    checkcells(flower4, flower5)
    checkcells(flower4, flower8)

    update()
    checkwin()
End Sub

Private Sub flower5_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles flower5.MouseDown
    checkcells(flower5, flower1)
    checkcells(flower5, flower4)
    checkcells(flower5, flower6)
    checkcells(flower5, flower9)
    update()
    checkwin()
End Sub

Private Sub flower6_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles flower6.MouseDown
    checkcells(flower6, flower2)
    checkcells(flower6, flower5)
    checkcells(flower6, flower7)
    checkcells(flower6, flower10)
    update()
    checkwin()
End Sub

Private Sub flower7_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles flower7.MouseDown
    checkcells(flower7, flower3)
    checkcells(flower7, flower6)
    checkcells(flower7, flower11)
    update()
    checkwin()
End Sub

Private Sub flower8_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles flower8.MouseDown
    checkcells(flower8, flower4)
    checkcells(flower8, flower9)
    checkcells(flower8, flower12)
    update()
    checkwin()
End Sub

Private Sub flower9_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles flower9.MouseDown
    checkcells(flower9, flower5)
    checkcells(flower9, flower8)
    checkcells(flower9, flower10)
    checkcells(flower9, flower13)
    update()
    checkwin()
End Sub

Private Sub flower10_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles flower10.MouseDown
    checkcells(flower10, flower6)
    checkcells(flower10, flower9)
    checkcells(flower10, flower11)
    checkcells(flower10, flower14)
    update()
    checkwin()
End Sub

Private Sub flower11_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles flower11.MouseDown
    checkcells(flower11, flower7)
    checkcells(flower11, flower10)
    checkcells(flower11, flower15)
    update()
    checkwin()
End Sub

Private Sub flower12_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles flower12.MouseDown
    checkcells(flower12, flower8)
    checkcells(flower12, flower13)
    update()
    checkwin()
End Sub

Private Sub flower13_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles flower13.MouseDown
    checkcells(flower13, flower9)
    checkcells(flower13, flower12)
    checkcells(flower13, flower14)
    update()
    checkwin()
End Sub

Private Sub flower14_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles flower14.MouseDown
    checkcells(flower14, flower10)
    checkcells(flower14, flower13)
    checkcells(flower14, flower15)
    update()
    checkwin()
End Sub

Private Sub flower15_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles flower15.MouseDown
    checkcells(flower15, flower11)
    checkcells(flower15, flower14)
    update()
    checkwin()
End Sub

Private Sub btnmix_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnmix.Click
    Randomize()
    Dim num(15) As Integer
    Dim rnd1 As Integer

    For i As Integer = 0 To 15
        rnd1 = Int(Rnd() * (16 - 1) + 1)
        Dim flag As Boolean = False
        Do While flag = False
            For x As Integer = 0 To 15
                If rnd1 = num(x) Then
                    flag = True

                End If
            Next

            If flag = True Then
                flag = False
                rnd1 = Int(Rnd() * (16 - 1) + 1)
            Else
                flag = True
            End If


        Loop
        num(i) = rnd1
        Dim h16 As New BitmapImage
        h16.BeginInit()
        h16.UriSource = New Uri("images2/h" & rnd1 & ".gif", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        h16.EndInit()
        images(i).Source = h16
    Next


End Sub

'Private Sub hint_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles hint.Click
'    Dim monaLisa As New BitmapImage
'    monaLisa.BeginInit()
'    monaLisa.UriSource = New Uri("images/monalisa.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
'    monaLisa.EndInit()
'    showMona.Source = monaLisa
'End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

If you make the stopwatch declaration in the class root , then initiate and start it in the window.loaded event and then reset it when the user shuffles the puzzle

Comment: in your class : dim sw as Stopwatch , then in window.loaded : sw = new Stopwatch(the parameters you want), in your method where the user shuffles the puzzle , sw.reset. You should be able to finish the rest on you own.

Comment: for more info on the stopwatch class see [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)